# How do i give null as an input through scanner in java

Tags: java, java.util.scanner

```
Scanner s= new Scanner(System.in);
    String a=s.next();
    System.out.println("this is: "+a);
```

I tried taking a NULL as input.But if i give null in the output console,it is treating it as a normal String.

Comment: Why would you want to do that tho? Perhaps you could read it as a normal String and then replace with null.

Answer (score 1):

`Scanner.next` returns a `String`. If you want to parse the input into some other type, you can use `Scanner.next*` methods, e.g. `Scanner.nextFloat`, etc.

If you need to handle "null" as a string to mean `null` you have to parse it yourself.